# Unity MouseLook script will not rotate on the X axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity PlayerLook script and as soon as I enable the vertical rotation code I can look vertically, but my side to side motion is locked, with the camera only jittering. Disabling the vertical rotation code allows my camera to look horizontally.

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour

{
    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;
    public Transform playerBody;
    float xRotation = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the mouselook and movement to work with this script I found online:

https://github.com/TheBozzz34/PR-Terrain-Multiplayer/blob/main/Assets/FirstPersion%20AIO%20Pack/FirstPersonAIO/FirstPersonAIO.cs

```
private void Update(){
 
        #region Look Settings - Update
 
            if(enableCameraMovement && !controllerPauseState){
            float mouseYInput = 0;
            float mouseXInput = 0;
            float camFOV = playerCamera.fieldOfView;
            if (cameraInputMethod == CameraInputMethod.Traditional || cameraInputMethod == CameraInputMethod.TraditionalWithConstraints){
                    mouseYInput = mouseInputInversion == InvertMouseInput.None || mouseInputInversion == InvertMouseInput.X ? Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") : -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
                    mouseXInput = mouseInputInversion == InvertMouseInput.None || mouseInputInversion == InvertMouseInput.Y ? Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") : -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
            }
            else{
                mouseXInput= Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * (mouseInputInversion == InvertMouseInput.None || mouseInputInversion == InvertMouseInput.Y ? 1 : -1);
            }            if(targetAngles.y > 180) { targetAngles.y -= 360; followAngles.y -= 360; } else if(targetAngles.y < -180) { targetAngles.y += 360; followAngles.y += 360; }
            if(targetAngles.x > 180) { targetAngles.x -= 360; followAngles.x -= 360; } else if(targetAngles.x < -180) { targetAngles.x += 360; followAngles.x += 360; }
            targetAngles.y += mouseXInput * (mouseSensitivity - ((baseCamFOV-camFOV)*fOVToMouseSensitivity)/6f);
            if (cameraInputMethod == CameraInputMethod.Traditional){ targetAngles.x += mouseYInput * (mouseSensitivity - ((baseCamFOV - camFOV) * fOVToMouseSensitivity) / 6f);}
            else {targetAngles.x = 0f;}
            targetAngles.x = Mathf.Clamp(targetAngles.x, -0.5f * verticalRotationRange, 0.5f * verticalRotationRange);
            followAngles = Vector3.SmoothDamp(followAngles, targetAngles, ref followVelocity, (cameraSmoothing)/100);
            
            playerCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-followAngles.x + originalRotation.x,0,0);
            transform.localRotation =  Quaternion.Euler(0, followAngles.y+originalRotation.y, 0);
        }
    
        #endregion
 
        #region Input Settings - Update
        if(canHoldJump ? (canJump && Input.GetButton("Jump")) : (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && canJump) ){
            jumpInput = true;
        }else if(Input.GetButtonUp("Jump")){jumpInput = false;}
        
        
        if(_crouchModifiers.useCrouch){
            if(!_crouchModifiers.toggleCrouch){ isCrouching = _crouchModifiers.crouchOverride || Input.GetKey(_crouchModifiers.crouchKey);}
            else if(Input.GetKeyDown(_crouchModifiers.crouchKey)){isCrouching = !isCrouching || _crouchModifiers.crouchOverride;}
            }
 
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Cancel")){ControllerPause();}
        #endregion
 
        #region Movement Settings - Update
        
        #endregion
 
        #region Headbobbing Settings - Update
 
        #endregion
 
    }
 
    private void FixedUpdate(){
 
        #region Look Settings - FixedUpdate
 
        #endregion
 
        #region Movement Settings - FixedUpdate
        
        if(useStamina){
            isSprinting = Input.GetKey(sprintKey) && !isCrouching && staminaInternal > 0 && (Mathf.Abs(fps_Rigidbody.velocity.x) > 0.01f || Mathf.Abs(fps_Rigidbody.velocity.z) > 0.01f);
            if(isSprinting){
                staminaInternal -= (staminaDepletionSpeed*2)*Time.deltaTime;
                if(drawStaminaMeter){
                    StaminaMeterBG.color = Vector4.MoveTowards(StaminaMeterBG.color, new Vector4(0,0,0,0.5f),0.15f);
                    StaminaMeter.color = Vector4.MoveTowards(StaminaMeter.color, new Vector4(1,1,1,1),0.15f);
                }
            }else if((!Input.GetKey(sprintKey)||Mathf.Abs(fps_Rigidbody.velocity.x)< 0.01f || Mathf.Abs(fps_Rigidbody.velocity.z)< 0.01f || isCrouching)&&staminaInternal<staminaLevel){
                staminaInternal += staminaDepletionSpeed*Time.deltaTime;
            }
                if(drawStaminaMeter){
                   if(staminaInternal==staminaLevel){ StaminaMeterBG.color = Vector4.MoveTowards(StaminaMeterBG.color, new Vector4(0,0,0,0),0.15f);
                    StaminaMeter.color = Vector4.MoveTowards(StaminaMeter.color, new Vector4(1,1,1,0),0.15f);}
                    float x = Mathf.Clamp(Mathf.SmoothDamp(StaminaMeter.transform.localScale.x,(staminaInternal/staminaLevel)*StaminaMeterBG.transform.localScale.x,ref smoothRef,(1)*Time.deltaTime,1),0.001f, StaminaMeterBG.transform.localScale.x);
                    StaminaMeter.transform.localScale = new Vector3(x,1,1); 
                }
                staminaInternal = Mathf.Clamp(staminaInternal,0,staminaLevel);
        } else{isSprinting = Input.GetKey(sprintKey);}
 
        Vector3 MoveDirection = Vector3.zero;
        speed = walkByDefault ? isCrouching ? walkSpeedInternal : (isSprinting ? sprintSpeedInternal : walkSpeedInternal) : (isSprinting ? walkSpeedInternal : sprintSpeedInternal);
  
 
        if(advanced.maxSlopeAngle>0){
            if(advanced.isTouchingUpright && advanced.isTouchingWalkable){
 
                MoveDirection = (transform.forward * inputXY.y * speed + transform.right * inputXY.x * walkSpeedInternal); 
                if(!didJump){fps_Rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;}              
                }
                else if(advanced.isTouchingUpright && !advanced.isTouchingWalkable){
                    fps_Rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
                }
                
                else{
                    
                fps_Rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
                MoveDirection = ((transform.forward * inputXY.y * speed + transform.right * inputXY.x * walkSpeedInternal) * (fps_Rigidbody.velocity.y>0.01f ? SlopeCheck() : 0.8f));
                }
        }
        else{
        MoveDirection = (transform.forward * inputXY.y * speed + transform.right * inputXY.x * walkSpeedInternal);
        }
 
        
            #region step logic
                RaycastHit WT;
                if(advanced.maxStepHeight > 0 && Physics.Raycast(transform.position - new Vector3(0,((capsule.height/2)*transform.localScale.y)-0.01f,0),MoveDirection,out WT,capsule.radius+0.15f,Physics.AllLayers,QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore) && Vector3.Angle(WT.normal, Vector3.up)>88){
                    RaycastHit ST;
                    if(!Physics.Raycast(transform.position - new Vector3(0,((capsule.height/2)*transform.localScale.y)-(advanced.maxStepHeight),0),MoveDirection,out ST,capsule.radius+0.25f,Physics.AllLayers,QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore)){
                        advanced.stairMiniHop = true;
                        transform.position += new Vector3(0,advanced.maxStepHeight*1.2f,0);
                    }
                }
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, MoveDirection,Color.red,0,false);
            #endregion
            
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        inputXY = new Vector2(horizontalInput, verticalInput);
        if(inputXY.magnitude > 1) { inputXY.Normalize(); }
 
            #region Jump
            yVelocity = fps_Rigidbody.velocity.y;
            
            if(IsGrounded && jumpInput && jumpPowerInternal > 0 && !didJump){
                if(advanced.maxSlopeAngle>0){
                    if(advanced.isTouchingFlat || advanced.isTouchingWalkable){
                            didJump=true;
                            jumpInput=false;
                            yVelocity += fps_Rigidbody.velocity.y<0.01f? jumpPowerInternal : jumpPowerInternal/3;
                            advanced.isTouchingWalkable = false;
                            advanced.isTouchingFlat = false;
                            advanced.isTouchingUpright = false;
                            fps_Rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
                    }
                    
                }else{
                    didJump=true;
                    jumpInput=false;
                    yVelocity += jumpPowerInternal;
                }
        
            }
 
            if(advanced.maxSlopeAngle>0){
            
            
            if(!didJump && advanced.lastKnownSlopeAngle>5 && advanced.isTouchingWalkable){
            yVelocity *= SlopeCheck()/4;
            }
            if(advanced.isTouchingUpright && !advanced.isTouchingWalkable && !didJump){
                yVelocity +=  Physics.gravity.y;
            }
        }
 
            #endregion
 
        if(playerCanMove && !controllerPauseState){
          fps_Rigidbody.velocity = MoveDirection+(Vector3.up * yVelocity);
 
        } else{fps_Rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;}
 
        if(inputXY.magnitude > 0 || !IsGrounded) {
            capsule.sharedMaterial = advanced.zeroFrictionMaterial;
        } else { capsule.sharedMaterial = advanced.highFrictionMaterial; }
  
        fps_Rigidbody.AddForce(Physics.gravity * (advanced.gravityMultiplier - 1));
        
        
        if(advanced.FOVKickAmount>0){
            if(isSprinting && !isCrouching && playerCamera.fieldOfView != (baseCamFOV+(advanced.FOVKickAmount*2)-0.01f)){
                if(Mathf.Abs(fps_Rigidbody.velocity.x)> 0.5f || Mathf.Abs(fps_Rigidbody.velocity.z)> 0.5f){
                    playerCamera.fieldOfView = Mathf.SmoothDamp(playerCamera.fieldOfView,baseCamFOV+(advanced.FOVKickAmount*2),ref advanced.fovRef,advanced.changeTime);
                    }
                
            }
            else if(playerCamera.fieldOfView != baseCamFOV){ playerCamera.fieldOfView = Mathf.SmoothDamp(playerCamera.fieldOfView,baseCamFOV,ref advanced.fovRef,advanced.changeTime*0.5f);}
            
        }
 
        if(_crouchModifiers.useCrouch) {
            
            if(isCrouching) {
                    capsule.height = Mathf.MoveTowards(capsule.height, _crouchModifiers.colliderHeight/1.5f, 5*Time.deltaTime);
                        walkSpeedInternal = walkSpeed*_crouchModifiers.crouchWalkSpeedMultiplier;
                        jumpPowerInternal = jumpPower* _crouchModifiers.crouchJumpPowerMultiplier;
 
                } else {
                capsule.height = Mathf.MoveTowards(capsule.height, _crouchModifiers.colliderHeight, 5*Time.deltaTime);    
                walkSpeedInternal = walkSpeed;
                sprintSpeedInternal = sprintSpeed;
                jumpPowerInternal = jumpPower;
            }
        }
 
 
 
 
        #endregion
 
        #region Headbobbing Settings - FixedUpdate
        float yPos = 0;
        float xPos = 0;
        float zTilt = 0;
        float xTilt = 0;
        float bobSwayFactor = 0;
        float bobFactor = 0;
        float strideLangthen = 0;
        float flatVel = 0;
        //calculate headbob freq
        if(useHeadbob == true || enableAudioSFX){
            Vector3 vel = (fps_Rigidbody.position - previousPosition) / Time.deltaTime;
            Vector3 velChange = vel - previousVelocity;
            previousPosition = fps_Rigidbody.position;
            previousVelocity = vel;
            springVelocity -= velChange.y;
            springVelocity -= springPosition * springElastic;
            springVelocity *= springDampen;
            springPosition += springVelocity * Time.deltaTime;
            springPosition = Mathf.Clamp(springPosition, -0.3f, 0.3f);
 
            if(Mathf.Abs(springVelocity) < springVelocityThreshold && Mathf.Abs(springPosition) < springPositionThreshold) { springPosition = 0; springVelocity = 0; }
            flatVel = new Vector3(vel.x, 0.0f, vel.z).magnitude;
            strideLangthen = 1 + (flatVel * ((headbobFrequency*2)/10));
            headbobCycle += (flatVel / strideLangthen) * (Time.deltaTime / headbobFrequency);
            bobFactor = Mathf.Sin(headbobCycle * Mathf.PI * 2);
            bobSwayFactor = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI * (2 * headbobCycle + 0.5f));
            bobFactor = 1 - (bobFactor * 0.5f + 1);
            bobFactor *= bobFactor;
 
            yPos = 0;
            xPos = 0;
            zTilt = 0;
            if(jumpLandIntensity>0 && !advanced.stairMiniHop){xTilt = -springPosition * (jumpLandIntensity*5.5f);}
            else if(!advanced.stairMiniHop){xTilt = -springPosition;}
 
            if(IsGrounded){
                if(new Vector3(vel.x, 0.0f, vel.z).magnitude < 0.1f) { headbobFade = Mathf.MoveTowards(headbobFade, 0.0f,0.5f); } else { headbobFade = Mathf.MoveTowards(headbobFade, 1.0f, Time.deltaTime); }
                float speedHeightFactor = 1 + (flatVel * 0.3f);
                xPos = -(headbobSideMovement/10) * headbobFade *bobSwayFactor;
                yPos = springPosition * (jumpLandIntensity/10) + bobFactor * (headbobHeight/10) * headbobFade * speedHeightFactor;
                zTilt = bobSwayFactor * (headbobSwayAngle/10) * headbobFade;
            }
        }
        //apply headbob position
            if(useHeadbob == true){
                if(fps_Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude >0.1f){
                    head.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(head.localPosition, snapHeadjointToCapsul ? (new Vector3(originalLocalPosition.x,(capsule.height/2)*head.localScale.y,originalLocalPosition.z)  + new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0)) : originalLocalPosition + new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0),0.5f);
                }else{
                    head.localPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp(head.localPosition, snapHeadjointToCapsul ? (new Vector3(originalLocalPosition.x,(capsule.height/2)*head.localScale.y,originalLocalPosition.z)  + new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0)) : originalLocalPosition + new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0),ref miscRefVel, 0.15f);
                }
                head.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xTilt, 0, zTilt);
                
           
        }
        #endregion
        
        #region Dynamic Footsteps
        if(enableAudioSFX){    
            if(fsmode == FSMode.Dynamic)
            {   
                RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
 
                if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit)){
                     
                    if(dynamicFootstep.materialMode == DynamicFootStep.matMode.physicMaterial){
                        dynamicFootstep.currentClipSet = (dynamicFootstep.woodPhysMat.Any() && dynamicFootstep.woodPhysMat.Contains(hit.collider.sharedMaterial) && dynamicFootstep.woodClipSet.Any()) ? // If standing on Wood
                        dynamicFootstep.woodClipSet : ((dynamicFootstep.grassPhysMat.Any() && dynamicFootstep.grassPhysMat.Contains(hit.collider.sharedMaterial) && dynamicFootstep.grassClipSet.Any()) ? // If standing on Grass
                        dynamicFootstep.grassClipSet : ((dynamicFootstep.metalAndGlassPhysMat.Any() && dynamicFootstep.metalAndGlassPhysMat.Contains(hit.collider.sharedMaterial) && dynamicFootstep.metalAndGlassClipSet.Any()) ? // If standing on Metal/Glass
                        dynamicFootstep.metalAndGlassClipSet : ((dynamicFootstep.rockAndConcretePhysMat.Any() && dynamicFootstep.rockAndConcretePhysMat.Contains(hit.collider.sharedMaterial) && dynamicFootstep.rockAndConcreteClipSet.Any()) ? // If standing on Rock/Concrete
                        dynamicFootstep.rockAndConcreteClipSet : ((dynamicFootstep.dirtAndGravelPhysMat.Any() && dynamicFootstep.dirtAndGravelPhysMat.Contains(hit.collider.sharedMaterial) && dynamicFootstep.dirtAndGravelClipSet.Any()) ? // If standing on Dirt/Gravle
                        dynamicFootstep.dirtAndGravelClipSet : ((dynamicFootstep.mudPhysMat.Any() && dynamicFootstep.mudPhysMat.Contains(hit.collider.sharedMaterial) && dynamicFootstep.mudClipSet.Any())? // If standing on Mud
                        dynamicFootstep.mudClipSet : ((dynamicFootstep.customPhysMat.Any() && dynamicFootstep.customPhysMat.Contains(hit.collider.sharedMaterial) && dynamicFootstep.customClipSet.Any())? // If standing on the custom material 
                        dynamicFootstep.customClipSet : footStepSounds)))))); // If material is unknown, fall back
                    }else if (hit.collider.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>()){
                        dynamicFootstep.currentClipSet = (dynamicFootstep.woodMat.Any() && dynamicFootstep.woodMat.Contains(hit.collider.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial) && dynamicFootstep.woodClipSet.Any()) ? // If standing on Wood
                        dynamicFootstep.woodClipSet : ((dynamicFootstep.grassMat.Any() && dynamicFootstep.grassMat.Contains(hit.collider.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial) && dynamicFootstep.grassClipSet.Any()) ? // If standing on Grass
                        dynamicFootstep.grassClipSet : ((dynamicFootstep.metalAndGlassMat.Any() && dynamicFootstep.metalAndGlassMat.Contains(hit.collider.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial) && dynamicFootstep.metalAndGlassClipSet.Any()) ? // If standing on Metal/Glass
                        dynamicFootstep.metalAndGlassClipSet : ((dynamicFootstep.rockAndConcreteMat.Any() && dynamicFootstep.rockAndConcreteMat.Contains(hit.collider.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial) && dynamicFootstep.rockAndConcreteClipSet.Any()) ? // If standing on Rock/Concrete
                        dynamicFootstep.rockAndConcreteClipSet : ((dynamicFootstep.dirtAndGravelMat.Any() && dynamicFootstep.dirtAndGravelMat.Contains(hit.collider.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial) && dynamicFootstep.dirtAndGravelClipSet.Any()) ? // If standing on Dirt/Gravle
                        dynamicFootstep.dirtAndGravelClipSet : ((dynamicFootstep.mudMat.Any() && dynamicFootstep.mudMat.Contains(hit.collider.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial) && dynamicFootstep.mudClipSet.Any())? // If standing on Mud
                        dynamicFootstep.mudClipSet : ((dynamicFootstep.customMat.Any() && dynamicFootstep.customMat.Contains(hit.collider.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial) && dynamicFootstep.customClipSet.Any())? // If standing on the custom material 
                        dynamicFootstep.customClipSet : footStepSounds.Any() ? footStepSounds : null)))))); // If material is unknown, fall back
                    }
 
                    if(IsGrounded)
                    {
                        if(!previousGrounded)
                        {
                            if(dynamicFootstep.currentClipSet.Any()) { audioSource.PlayOneShot(dynamicFootstep.currentClipSet[Random.Range(0, dynamicFootstep.currentClipSet.Count)],Volume/10); }
                            nextStepTime = headbobCycle + 0.5f;
                        } else
                        {
                            if(headbobCycle > nextStepTime)
                            {
                                nextStepTime = headbobCycle + 0.5f;
                                if(dynamicFootstep.currentClipSet.Any()){ audioSource.PlayOneShot(dynamicFootstep.currentClipSet[Random.Range(0, dynamicFootstep.currentClipSet.Count)],Volume/10); }
                            }
                        }
                        previousGrounded = true;
                    } else
                    {
                        if(previousGrounded)
                        {
                            if(dynamicFootstep.currentClipSet.Any()){ audioSource.PlayOneShot(dynamicFootstep.currentClipSet[Random.Range(0, dynamicFootstep.currentClipSet.Count)],Volume/10); }
                        }
                        previousGrounded = false;
                    }
 
                } else {
                    dynamicFootstep.currentClipSet = footStepSounds;
                    if(IsGrounded)
                    {
                        if(!previousGrounded)
                        {
                            if(landSound){ audioSource.PlayOneShot(landSound,Volume/10); }
                            nextStepTime = headbobCycle + 0.5f;
                        } else
                        {
                            if(headbobCycle > nextStepTime)
                            {
                                nextStepTime = headbobCycle + 0.5f;
                                int n = Random.Range(0, footStepSounds.Count);
                                if(footStepSounds.Any()){ audioSource.PlayOneShot(footStepSounds[n],Volume/10); }
                                footStepSounds[n] = footStepSounds[0];
                            }
                        }
                        previousGrounded = true;
                    } else
                    {
                        if(previousGrounded)
                        {
                            if(jumpSound){ audioSource.PlayOneShot(jumpSound,Volume/10); }
                        }
                        previousGrounded = false;
                    }
                }
                
            } else
            {
                if(IsGrounded)
                {
                    if(!previousGrounded)
                    {
                        if(landSound) { audioSource.PlayOneShot(landSound,Volume/10); }
                        nextStepTime = headbobCycle + 0.5f;
                    } else
                    {
                        if(headbobCycle > nextStepTime)
                        {
                            nextStepTime = headbobCycle + 0.5f;
                            int n = Random.Range(0, footStepSounds.Count);
                            if(footStepSounds.Any() && footStepSounds[n] != null){ audioSource.PlayOneShot(footStepSounds[n],Volume/10);}
                            
                        }
                    }
                    previousGrounded = true;
                } else
                {
                    if(previousGrounded)
                    {
                        if(jumpSound) { audioSource.PlayOneShot(jumpSound,Volume/10); }
                    }
                    previousGrounded = false;
                }
            }
 
        }
        #endregion
 
        #region  Reset Checks
 
        IsGrounded = false;
        
        if(advanced.maxSlopeAngle>0){
            if(advanced.isTouchingFlat || advanced.isTouchingWalkable || advanced.isTouchingUpright){didJump = false;}
            advanced.isTouchingWalkable = false;
            advanced.isTouchingUpright = false;
            advanced.isTouchingFlat = false;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making an FPS game I was working on one not too long ago and got a solution like, create a new script and put it in the main camera, then in unity drag and drop your player object to the Player Body component on the Main Camera Script that you just created (Keep note that the script name must be named "MouseDir" for it to work):

I don't know why the Mouse X does not work I had the same problem awhile ago.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseDir : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform playerBody;

    public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
    public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
    public float sensitivityX = 15F;
    public float sensitivityY = 15F;

    public float minimumX = -360F;
    public float maximumX = 360F;

    public float minimumY = -60F;
    public float maximumY = 60F;

    float rotationY = 0F;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = playerBody.transform.position;

        if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY)
        {
            float rotationX = transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;

            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, rotationX, 0);
            playerBody.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, rotationX, 0);
        }
        else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX, 0);
            playerBody.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X ") * sensitivityX, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure why, but does script not seem to work either, Thankfully I did get it working in the end.

Comment: Good! Can you post the solution here? It may be helpful to others!

Comment: Ah yes sorry I apologize, I could not answer my question till the following day, and promptly forgot to post the answer the next day.